# If $x\ge 1$ and $\sum_{x\in U}\log(x)>\sum_{x\in L}\log (x)$, then $\sum_{x\in U}x>\sum_{x\in L}x$

Tags: calculus, logarithms

I have a question.

I have no clue if the below inequality involving the sum of logarithms is true:

> If $x\ge 1$ and $$\sum_{x\in U}\log(x)>\sum_{x\in L}\log (x)$$ then $$\sum_{x\in U}x>\sum_{x\in L}x$$

thank you!

Comment: Okay, what are the sets $U$ ans $L$? You have to give us context.

Comment: Could you use the fact that $\log(x)$ an increasing function on $x>0$?

Comment: Try out some values of $x$. Some suggestions, consider $x=e$, $e^{1/2}$, $e^{1/3}$.

Comment: Nice descriptive title.  Your question's title helps mathSE reviewers decide whether to examine your question based on whether they favor posters who either are or are not lost.

Comment: Oh, U and L is just subset of the set of real numbers. (Smallest element in both U and L is greater than or equal to 1) Also, U and L are disjoint sets.

Comment: I imagine $U$ and $L$ are arbitrary sets?

Comment: Ah @std I saw your comment after I posted my last one!

Comment: Consider $U = \{2.99,2.98\}$ and $L = \{2,4\}$.  The fact that the product of the elements in $U$ is greater than the product of the elements in $L$, does not prevent the sum of the elements in $U$ from being less than the sum of the elements in $L$.

Comment: @user2661923 Thankyou I think i found a countexample. if U = {2, 3} and L={1, 5}, then product of the elements in U is greater than L's but sum of the elements in U is less than L's

Comment: I think the new title makes this post hard to be searched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for simplicity, assume $\log$ means log based $10$. Then choose $U=\{100,1000\}$ and $L=\{10000\}$. Then you get $$\log_{10}100+\log_{10}1000=2+3>4$$but $$100+1000=1100<10000$$

Comment: Thank you Andrei! what a simple proof...!  I feel embarrassed now.